# Are the Infinity Stones intentionally coloured in rainbow colours?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

It seems to me, that the Infinity Stones are coloured not randomly, but in rainbow colours. Is this intentional?

- Reality Stone - red
- Soul Stone - orange
- Mind Stone - yellow
- Time Stone - green
- Space Stone - blue (on the picture, it is not actually blue, but in the film, it is)
- Power Stone - purple

[image: stones]

Comment: What other colors are there?

Comment: If they were, they're missing a color ... Indigo. I'm sure they're colored almost as the rainbow so you, the viewer, can tell the difference. I mean, if they had six stones of different shades of red, would be kind of hard to tell the difference. *Is that a bright red or a bright orange red?*

Comment: Rainbow has seven colours but LGBT rainbow flag do have this six coulurs only.

Comment: Wong said that virgin universe created the stones after the big bang. So it's before the rainbows. (in-universe)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: `If they were, they're missing a color ... Indigo` Are you suggesting Thanos himself completes the set? ;)

Comment: @Flater - Hadn't thought of that, but good one! :o) He surely could fill that bill!

Comment: Refresh http://randomcolour.com/ six times... it's very unlikely that you'll get six colors that are as visually pleasing or distinct as the picture you show. Having supers fight over 6 rocks that are different shades of brown just wouldn't look as cool.

Comment: I think "is this intentional" is the wrong question to ask. If the question was "Why is each infinity stone a distinct color of the rainbow", I'd give this question an upvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The six shown colors are simply as visually distinct from one another as they can be, as they are (roughly) equidistantly distributed along the color spectrum.

Quite obviously, the rainbow is defined as the color spectrum, to there is some overlap between the two color palettes, **but that doesn't mean that the stones are colored as an intentional reference to a rainbow**.

The color of the stones is not relevant to the plot. The plot never established particular colors being necessary. From a plotwise perspective, the stones could have been the same color.

But that wouldn't be visually pleasing. Having the stones distributed among the color spectrum indirectly suggests that they are a complete set, plus it makes stones easily identifiable without needing someone to always verbally identify a stone.